# Trying to print out comission and table in console

Tags: java

So I have a homework assignment that requires me to do the following:

- The company has recently changed its total annual compensation policy to improve sales
- A salesperson will continue to earn a fixed salary of $55,000.00. The current sales target for every salesperson is $100,000.00.
- The sales incentive will only start when 80% of the sales target is met. The current commission is 14% of total sales.
- If a salesperson exceeds the sales target, the commission will increase based on an acceleration factor. The acceleration factor is 1.40.
- The application should ask the user to enter annual sales, and it should display the total annual compensation.
- The application should also display a table of potential annual compensation that the salesperson could have earned, in $5,000.00 increments above the salesperson's annual sales, unitl it reaches 50% above the salesperson's annual sales.

So, this is an example of the table I have to create, and it is assuming total annual sales of $100,000.00. So it would look something like this:

```
Total Sales Total Compensation
------------------------------------------------------------------
100,000 <<Program Calculated Value>>
105,000 <<Program Calculated Value>>
110,000 <<Program Calculated Value>>
115,000 <<Program Calculated Value>>
120,000 <<Program Calculated Value>>
125,000 <<Program Calculated Value>>
130,000 <<Program Calculated Value>>
135,000 <<Program Calculated Value>>
140,000 <<Program Calculated Value>>
145,000 <<Program Calculated Value>>
150,000 <<Program Calculated Value>>
```

The above table is an example! It will be different based on the annual sales that is input.

The application must also meet these technical requirements:

- The application should have at least one class, in addition to the applications controlling class
- Your code must use a method to do the calculation for compensation
- The source code must demonstrate the use of conditional and looping structures
- There should be proper documentation

Basically, I am building this on top of the previous weeks assignment which was to to build a app that calculates the total annual compensation of a salesperson.

- A salesperson will earn a fixed slary of $55,000.00
- A salespeson will also receive a commission as a sales incentive. Commission is a percentage of the salesperson's annual sales. The current commission is 14% of total sales.
- The total annual compensation is the fixed salary plus the commission earned.

So, the problem I am having is, I am very confused with this. And I am getting an error which I will show below, and when I run the program I get this result:

```
run:
This is a console based application that calculates the total annual compensation of a salesperson.
Just follow along with the prompts, and insert the correct data.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Enter salesperson's annual sales
/* NOTE: I INSERTED THE BELOW VALUE OF 100000 */
100000
Total annual compensation: $69000.00
0.0
$55000.00
Total Sales      Total Compensation
ERROR: Please enter a valid sales amount.
Press enter to exit.
```

So in the while loop I get the error:

```
'void' type not allowed here
'void' type not allowed here
not a statement
----
(Alt-Enter shows hint)
```

This is displayed here:

```
while (annualSales <= annualSalesTable) {
    System.out.println(annualSales) + "\t" + calculate.printAnnualCompensation();
    annualSales = annualSales + 5000;
}
```

I don't know how to fix this. Here is the code, there are two classes SalesPerson.java which is the main class, and then Calculate.java:

SalesPerson.java:

```
package salesperson;

import java.io.IOException
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SalesPerson {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("This is a console based application that calculates the total annual compensation");
        System.out.println("Just follow along with the prompts, and insert the correct data.");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------\n");

        getInput(in);

        try {
            System.out.println("Press Enter to exit");
            System.in.read();
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void getInput(Scanner in) {
        Calculate calculate = new Calculate();
        double annualSales;

        try {
            System.out.println("Enter salesperson's annual sales");
            if(in.hasNextDouble()) {
                annualSales = in.nextDouble();

                if (annualSales == 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("Please enter a valid annual sales amount.");
                }
                else 
                {
                     double tot = calculate.calcCompensation(annualSales);
                     DecimalFormat decFormat = new DecimalFormat(".00");
                     System.out.println("Total annual compensation: " + "$" + decFormat(tot));
                     /* NOTE: I DO NOT KNOW HOW TO GET annualSales to populate this! */
                     calculate.printAnnualCompensation();

                     System.out.println();
                     System.out.println("Total Sales\tTotal Compensation");

                     double annualSaleTable = annualSales * 1.5;

                     while(annualSales <= annualSaleTable) {
                         System.out.println(annualSales) + "\t" + calculate.printAnnualCompensation(); /* ERROR HERE */
                         annualSales = annualSales + 5000;
                     }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Please enter a valid sales amount.");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Calculate.java class:

```
package salesperson;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Calculate {
    private double annualSales;
    private double comissionRate = 0.14;
    private double fixedSalary = 55000.00;
    private double salesTarget = 100000.00;
    private double accelerationFactor = 1.40;

    public double calcCompensation(double annualSales) {
        // Sets the annual salary to multiply by commission rate and then assign the total to currentComm
        double currentComm = annualSales * comissionRate;
        // Adds currentComm variable to the fixSalary variable and assigns that total to the "total" variable
        double total = fixedSalary + currentComm;

        return total;
    }

    public double getCommission() {
        return this.annualSales * this.comissionRate;
    }

    public double annualSales(double anSales) {
        annualSales = anSales;
        return annualSales;
    }

    public void printAnnualCompensation() { /* THIS IS THROWING ERROR ON MAIN CLASS */
        DecimalFormat decFormat = new DecimalFormat(".00");

        /** 
          * Total sales that is less than 80% of the target = no commission
          * Total sales that is between 80% of the target and the less than the target - 14%
          * Total sales that is equal or exceeds the target sales is 14% * 1.4 or 19.6%
         */

        double total = this.fixedSalary;

        // Getting the percentage of the target achieved
        double percentage = (this.annualSales / this.salesTarget) * 100;
        System.out.println(percentage);

        if (percentage < 80) {
            // Do nothing, don't get commission if the percentage is less than 80% of target
        } else if(percentage > 80 && percentage < 100) {
            // Total = annualSalary + commission
            total += getCommission();
        } else if (percentage >= 100) {
            // total = annualSalary + (commission * accelerationFactor);
            total += (getCommission() * this.accelerationFactor);
        }

        System.out.println("$" + decFormat + format(total));
    }
}
```

So, this is not working at all for me, I am still needing the table to work which I can not get. I also need it to meet the requirements, but to me it seems like I have a lot of code that is just sitting around doing nothing or I am replicating everything, but I do not know how to clean it up.

I do not expect you guys to do it for me, I just need help doing this, because I am getting so lost and frustrated!!

Thanks for any help you can give me!

Answer (score 0):

The error in this line

```
System.out.println(annualSales) + "\t" + calculate.printAnnualCompensation();
```

is that you try to use the `+` opertor with a left side of type `void`. You wanted to do something like this:

```
System.out.println(annualSales + "\t" + calculate.printAnnualCompensation());
```